# Find the minimum of $P=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}+2xy$ with $xy\geq 1$.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have a problem when finding the minimum of $P=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}+2xy$ with $xy\geq 1$.
I can prove directly $P \geq 3$ by multiply to the orther side, but i want to find the minimum with inequality.
I tried to used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but get stuck. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}-\frac{2}{1+xy}=\frac{(x-y)^2(xy-1)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+xy)}\geq0.$$
Thus, by AM-GM $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+y^2}+2xy\geq\frac{2}{1+xy}+2xy\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2}{2xy}+2xy=\frac{1}{xy}+xy+xy\geq2+1=3.$$

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! the first line is awesome

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, there is often no better method than simply differentiating. Let $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|xy > 1\}$, thus $\overline{\Omega} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|xy \geqslant 1\}$ and $P : (x,y) \mapsto \frac{1}{1 + x^2} + \frac{1}{1 + y^2} + 2xy$ defined and smooth on $\overline{\Omega}$. We clearly have $P \geqslant 2$ so $P$ is bounded from below. The condition $xy \geqslant 1$ implies that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero and have the same sign and $P$ is even so it is enough to study it on the positive $x$ and $y$. From now, assume $x,y > 0$.

Then, at any point $(x,y)$,
$$
\partial_xP(x,y) = -\frac{2x}{(1 + x^2)^2} + 2y, \quad \partial_yP(x,y) = -\frac{2y}{(1 + y^2)^2} + 2x.
$$
If both vanish, then $y = \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^2}$ because $\partial_xP(x,y) = 0$. Therefore, $y \leqslant x$. Symmetrically, $x \leqslant y$ because $\partial_yP(x,y) = 0$. It implies that $x = y$ and so $x = \frac{x}{(1 + x^2)^2}$ thus $x = 0$. The point $(0,0)$ doesn't belong to $\overline{\Omega}$ so $\nabla P$ doesn't vanish. It means that $P$ has no local minima on $\Omega$.

If we study what happens on $\partial\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_+^{*2}|xy = 1\}$, we have
$$
P(x,y) = P\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2} + \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1} + 2 = 3.
$$
There are two possibilities now :
$(1)$ $P$ has no minima on $\overline{\Omega}$ (it means its $\inf$ is not reached), which is possible since $\overline{\Omega}$ is not compact.
$(2)$ $P$ has a minimum on $\overline{\Omega}$. In this case, this minimum is not reached in $\Omega$ because the gradient would vanish, thus it is on $\partial\Omega$ and on this set, $P = 3$ so $\min(P) = 3$.

If you can prove as you said that $P \geqslant 3$, we are necessarily in the case $(2)$ because case $(1)$ implies $\inf(P) < P(1,1) = 3$.

Remark : if you can prove that $P \geqslant 3$ and you notice that $P(1,1) = 3$, you directly have with no more computation that $\min(P)$ exists and equals $3$.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i used to think about this way but this is an problem in high school inequality so i can't use this way :|